# Google Firebase Notification launching different Activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a Firebase notification that is sent to my device perfectly. For some reason, when i click on the notification it launches another Activity instead of the Activity i have declared in my method onMessage received. I have checked all possible reasons and cannot find the problem.
When i click on the notification i want to send the message to another activity.

This is my codes below:

```
public class FireMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.d("Msg", "Message received ["+remoteMessage.getData().toString()+"]");
    String notificationMessage = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    String notificationTitle = "LendingSquare Alert!";
    int notificationIndex = 1410;

    String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setContentText(notificationMessage);
    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationIndex, mBuilder.build());

}
}
```

Comment: Try starting the activity directly from `resultIntent` using `startActivity` rather than adding it to the `BackStack` and fetching it again.

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury can you show me how to do that?

Comment: `startActivity(resultIntent)`